# SoapUI test suite properties are not working as expected while integration with Robot framework

Tags: soapui, jython, robotframework, selenium2library, jython-2.7

```
SoapUI Project C:\Users\GSIS 2.7 - CIM.20-soapui-project.xml
SoapUI Set Project Property ServiceEndpoint=http://hwrllb01/GSIS_APIService/cim_2_0/CIMService.svc # set a single property |
SoapUI Set Project Property Username=bk # set a single property |
SoapUI Set Project Property Username=***** # set a single property |
```

Above are all the properties I am using for running the test case.
`SoapUI Project C:\Users\GSIS 2.7 - CIM.20-soapui-project.xml` is able working as expected.

Rest other properties its not getting update which I had mentioned above.It's always hitting the same saved properties. I need it automated to hit from my ##scripts.

Comment: How are you passing values? how are you running the test suites? It appears that there isn't anything to do with robotframework, Isn't it?

Comment: Below are the variables through which I am passing the values:  
SoapUI Set Project Property ServiceEndpoint=http://hwrllb01/GSIS_APIService/cim_2_0/CIMService.svc # set a single property |
SoapUI Set Project Property Username=bk 
SoapUI Set Project Property Username=*****                                                           above "SoapUI set Project Property" are the robot framework keyword.

Comment: It was just repeated and does not help.

Comment: I am running the test case in .bat file through jybot.

Comment: Anyone who can help me on this ..please

Comment: Unfortunately, could not imagine how and what you are trying to achieve due the lack of details.